# Error creating bean with name 'mongoTemplate'

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating     bean with name 'mongoTemplate' 
>   defined in class com.socketcruiter.config.SpringMongoConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; 
>   nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
>   Factory method [public org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration.mongoTemplate() 
>   throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>    Error creating bean with name 'mappingMongoConverter' defined in class com.socketcruiter.config.SpringMongoConfig: 
>    Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
>    Factory method [public org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter org.springframework.data.mongodb.config.AbstractMongoConfiguration.mappingMongoConverter() 
>    throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
>    org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/ClassTypeInformation;

i have the following config

```
<mongo:mongo host="127.0.0.1" port="27017" />
<mongo:db-factory dbname="ssss" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
```

and im using 
    
            org.springframework.data
            spring-data-mongodb
            1.7.1.RELEASE

Comment: `nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.from(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/springframework/data/util/ClassTypeInformation;`

You aren't including a jar that has that class in it. Usually a version mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the correct jar in your class path.
You would need spring-data-commons-core jar, here is the latest version:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons-core/1.4.1.RELEASE

Comment: i have the following in my pom.xml  still getiting the same error what are the right versions to work? <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>   <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>       <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
   <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>   <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.2</version>   <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>

Answer (score 0):

If the user name and password of your monogodb are empty, comment it out in the configuration file and debug it again.